# SAS- if columnA or columnB or columnC contains '1' then column1 ='1'

Tags: sas, short

In my SAS I have a data set as follows:

```
  columnA columnB columnC 
     1      2       .    
     3      .       .
```

I would like to create the new variables column1, column2, and column3 depending on the values in the forst 3 column as below, where 1=Yes, and 2=No.

```
 columnA columnB columnC column1 column2 column3
    1       2       .       1       1       2
    3       .       .       2       2       1
```

Is there a shorter way to write this than as follows:

```
 If columnA = 1 or columnB = 1 or columnC = 1 then column1=1; else column1=2;
```

Comment: Why are you coding 1=Yes and 2=No instead of the default boolen values of  0=No and 1=Yes?

Answer (score 1):

This is when arrays become your best friend. I don't know about you, but I hate repetitive work. I go out of my way to specifically find a non-repetitive way of doing things. From the looks of it, today is that day for you! Let's get you acquainted with arrays.

**One way to do it**

```
data want;
    set have;

    array alpha_column[*] columnA--columnC;
    array bin_column[3] _TEMPORARY_;

    /* Convert to your columns to binary to make this easier to work with:
       1 = yes
       0 = no
    */
    do i = 1 to dim(bin_column);
        bin_column[i] = (alpha_column[i] = 1);
    end;

    /* If any of the columns are yes, then column1 = 1 */
    column1 = (sum(of bin_column[*]) > 0);

    drop i;
run;
```

**Explanation**

**`array alpha_column[*] columnA--columnC;`**

This tells SAS to create an array of variables based off of columnA, columnB, and columnC. `--` is a shortcut that tells SAS to include all of the variables between `columnA` and `columnC`.  `[*]` tells SAS to count the size of the array automatically.

You can now refer to each column using a single variable. `alpha_column[1]` points to columnA. `alpha_column[2]` points to columnB, etc.

**`array bin_column[3] _TEMPORARY_;`**

This tells SAS to create a temporary in-memory array with 3 variables. They are not written to the output dataset when `_TEMPORARY_` is specified. We want this to convert the yes/no values into simple binary values.

```
do i = 1 to dim(bin_column);
    bin_column[i] = (alpha_column[i] = 1);
end;
```

Iterate over all columns in the array `bin_column`. `dim(bin_column)` tells SAS to pull the size of the array to prevent out-of-bounds array errors. This statement checks if every value of `alpha_column` is 1. If it is, `bin_column` is 1. Otherwise, `bin_column` is 0.

The statement `variable = (boolean test statement)` is a helpful shortcut in SAS to create binary variables in a single step.

**`column1 = (sum(of bin_column[*]) > 0)`**

This performs a sum over the entire array using the `of` operator. `sum(of array[*]`, `sum(of var1-var3)`, and `sum(of var:)` are all shortcuts to prevent having to type over and over again: `sum(var1, var2, var3, var4, ...)`.

Here we're saying if any of the binary columns are 1 then the total sum of those columns must be > 0. If they are, someone said yes. If they aren't, someone said no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WHICHN()` (if your values are actually character strings then use `whichc()` instead).  It will return zero if the value is not found. So just test if the value is not zero.  To set COLUMN1 to 0 or 1 values there is no need for IF/THEN, just assign the result of the boolean expression to the variable.

```
column1 = 0 < whichn(1,of columnA columnB columnC);
```

You can make minor adjustments to test for a value of 2 or 3 instead.  Or if you really want to code NO as 2 instead of zero.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tom `WHICHN` is the way to go.  Subtract logic 0(false)/1(true) from 2 to compute your encoding 1(true)/2(false)

```
column1 = 2 - (whichn(1,of columnA columnB columnC) ne 0);
column2 = 2 - (whichn(2,of columnA columnB columnC) ne 0);
column3 = 2 - (whichn(3,of columnA columnB columnC) ne 0);
```